# EF Core 6 Navigation Property not updated on database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

My Models (changed for brevity):

```
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tutorial>? Tutorials { get; set; }
}

public class Tutorial
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

Im trying to persist a course which consists a list of tutorials on sqlite db. Here's a simple version of my code.

```
// create a new Course with user input name
// get list of tutorials by looping through data from external api
course.Tutorials = tutorialsAppendedInsideForLoop();
context.Courses.Add(course);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

My `Course` item was saved on db. But surprisingly only the last item in my `Tutorials` list got persisted. Not the whole list.

Im struggling to find the issue here.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the forloop code:

```
private List<Tutorial> TutorialsAppendedInsideForLoop(Course course)
{
    var tuts = CallToExternalApi();

    var tutorials = new List<Tutorial>();

    for (int i = 0; i < tuts.Count; i++)
    {
        var tutorial = new Tutorial
        {
            Title = tuts[i].Name,
            Course = course
        };

        tutorials.Add(tutorial);                        
    }

    return tutorials;
}
```

Comment: Show us your code for `tutorialsAppendedInsideForLoop()`.

Comment: My best guess is that `tutorialsAppendedInsideForLoop()` is written in a way that the returned collection only contains one unique Tutorial. Perhaps the Tutorials all have the same non-zero ID? Or maybe you create only one `new Tutorial()` and then your loop fills out its properties multiple times and adds the same instance to the collection over and over again?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have updated the question.

Comment: When I put a debug point and check the variable, the complete list is loaded. However for some reason it is not persisted properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can try set the course into TutorialList

```
foreach(var tutorial in tutorials)
{
    tutorial.Course = course;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Already setting it inside the forloop. But same result.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at wrong place for the bug.  Issue is not in the for loop. DB is skipping other records because I have incorrectly set the relationships in Fluent API. Once I got rid of that bug, it's working perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add the courses inside the foreach:

```
var course = context.Courses.Where(x => x.Id == id);

foreach (var tutorial in tutorials)
{
   course.Tutorials.Add(tutorial);
}

context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).